# shell custom window/tab titles using ssh

Tags: bash, ubuntu, ssh, terminal

I work with a number of open windows and tabs.  To keep them straight I wanted to add specific words to their titles so it's possible to quickly jump between them.  Changing the preferences in my terminal emulator program worked well for connecting to my local machine.  But when connected to a remote machine using ssh, my preferences were being ignored.  Both the shell window title and tab titles would change every time I did a cd command.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [Redditor posguy99](https://old.reddit.com/r/osx/comments/ewwpx1/terminal_edited_windowtab_titles_overridden_in/), I learned that the remote machine's bash preferences (.bashrc) was controlling the titles.  By commenting out the following code, the custom window/tab titles entered into my emulator program's preferences seem to be persistent...

```
# If this is an xterm set the title to user@host:dir
# case "$TERM" in
# xterm*|rxvt*)
#     PS1="\[\e]0;${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h: \w\a\]$PS1"
#     ;;
# *)
#     ;;
# esac
```